# Angular | Ionic 3 : How to hide and change width to button depending of condition?

Tags: angular, ionic3

I'm developing a booking app with Ionic 3 and Angular.
I've used ion-stepper to dive my booking form in multiples steps.

Now my goal is to change the button depending on steps. I know that through `e` I can get the current steps. This is my `.ts` file:

```
import {Component, Renderer, ViewChild, NgZone} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, AlertController, Content} from 'ionic-angular';

import {IonicStepperComponent} from 'ionic-stepper';

@IonicPage()
@Component({

    selector: 'page-add-apartment',
    templateUrl: 'add-apartment.html',
})

export class AddApartment {

    @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
    @ViewChild('stepper') stepper: IonicStepperComponent;
    header: any;
    headerHeight: any;
    translateAmt: any;
    currentNumber = 0;

    textStep = 'Continua';

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public renderer: Renderer, public zone: NgZone) {
    }

    next() {
        this.stepper.nextStep();
    }

    previous() {
        this.stepper.previousStep();
    }

    selectChange(e) {
        console.log(e);
        if ( e === 6 )
        {
            this.textStep = 'Pubblica';
        }
    }

    decrement () {
        if(this.currentNumber>0){
            this.currentNumber--;}
    }

    increment() {
        this.currentNumber++;
    }

}
```

And here is my view:

```
<ion-footer col-sm-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2 col-lg-6 offset-lg-3 col-xl-6 offset-xl-3>
<ion-toolbar>
    <ion-grid class="bottom_0" no-padding>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col class="left_xs" col-2>
                <button ion-button color="light" large (click)="previous()">
                    <ion-icon name="ios-arrow-back"></ion-icon>
                </button>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col class="right_xs" col-10>
                <button ion-button class="btn_block" large (click)="next()">
                    {{ textStep }}
                </button>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
</ion-toolbar>
```

If you see i have `selectChange(e)` that told me the current step. I know  I can switch between steps with `if ( e === numberOfPage )`.

Now my question is, how can I hide the button back in view if `e` is the first step (to only show button "Continua") and how can I change its width from col-10 to col-12?

Answer (score 0):

Use `*ngIf="currentNumber === 1"` to conditionally show/hide the *"Previous"* button

Also to dynamically set the width of the *"Next"* button, you can use `[ngStyle]`
:

```
<ion-footer col-sm-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2 col-lg-6 offset-lg-3 col-xl-6 offset-xl-3>
<ion-toolbar>
    <ion-grid class="bottom_0" no-padding>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col class="left_xs" col-2>
                <button *ngIf="currentNumber === 1" ion-button color="light" large (click)="previous()">
                    <ion-icon name="ios-arrow-back"></ion-icon>
                </button>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col class="right_xs" col-10>
                <button ion-button [ngStyle]="{ 'width': (currentNumber === 1) ? '200px': '100px' }" class="btn_block" large (click)="next()">
                    {{ textStep }}
                </button>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
</ion-toolbar>
```

Comment: `currentNumber` is referred to increase decrease product, so not work on button, and than how can say that at that steps the button is hide; plus how your hint help me to change the col width of _next_ button?

Comment: Well `currentNumber` is a property on your Component. So it will be accessible in the template. Just initialize it to 1 instead of 0 and it should work.